# Creating a real_escape_string() method for systems with magic quotes enabled

Tags: php, mysql, oop, mysqli, magic-quotes-gpc

The book I'm learning PHP from says that in order to prevent people using things like quotes to alter the query, you should use the real_escape_string function. The author then goes on to say that on some older systems, where magic quotes is enabled, using real_escape_string could end up double escaping some characters, so he creates this function:

```
<?php
    function mysql_fix_string($conn, $string) {
        if (get_magic_quotes_gpc()) $string = stripslashes($string);
        return $conn->real_escape_string($string);
    }
?>
```

Would it be okay to turn this into a method in an extended class of the mysqli class? (There isn't any real reason why I wanted to, other than that I wanted to pass in as few arguments as possible.)

If so, is this the right way to do it?

```
class mysqli_extended extends mysqli {
    public function fix_string($string) {
        if(get_magic_quotes_gpc()) {
            $string = stripslashes($string);
        }
        return $this->real_escape_string($string);
    }
}
```

And is this a situation where a static method makes more sense? If so, how could it be rewritten as a static method, and if not, then why?

---

Since I just asked like a million questions, I'll put a summary of them here:

1. Is it okay to create a method for this purpose. (Are there any drawbacks to this?)
2. Is the above code the correct way to do so?
3. Should it be a static method?
4. How would you make it a static method?

Comment: book is way old sir.

get a newer version :)

Comment: `if (get_magic_quotes_gpc()) exit ('server broken');`

Comment: @Mubin I actually bought the book because it was published only last year! But seeing as everyone is saying that it's no longer an issue,  I suppose it must have been mistakenly left in from a previous edition. Thanks for the info, however!

Comment: @Dagon `if (PHP_VERSION_ID < 50500) die("unsupported PHP version")` (cf. http://php.net/eol.php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Magic quotes has been deprecated as of php 5.3 and is removed in 5.4.  I recommend [learn php the right way](http://www.phptherightway.com/)

Comment: The book I'm using did mention that, but it also said that there are still quite a few systems that are running outdated versions of php, so it should be done as a precaution. Is this information outdated? Is it now safe to assume that any server will be of a version higher than that?

Comment: While there are plenty of older servers that still use magic quotes, more and more php development is moving towards the newer versions.  I personally would not spend time on it unless you are confronted with that issue.  I'm just glad you are aware of it unlike many php devs :)

Comment: I see, thanks for the info. So are the only php versions that need to be put into consideration are the ones higher than those on this list from the php.net website? http://php.net/eol.php

Comment: Yeah if you are using anything below 5.3, you will want to get that fixed.  It depends on the individual sites.  Not all php code written for lower versions uses magic quotes.  It was more of a thing back in php 4 and lower, so it depends on the code base.  It is good you are aware of it and know to look out for it, but I wouldn't spend a lot of time learning to remedy it unless you are confronted with that situation.  A lot of custom sites wrote their own esaping functions to handle this (and others didn't).